# download file in python

Tags: python, download

when i want download jpeg in python with this code:

```
def download(url, dest):
    s = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    content = s.read()
    s.close()
    d = open(dest,'w')
    d.write(content)
    d.close()
```

the file on hdd is not readable but when i open jpeg in mozilla its ok,
i am using windows and python 2.6
some solutions? thanks

Comment: Surely a function that does the downloads for you would be a better answer? This one allows for a report hook, and a download location to be set

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are opening the file in text mode and corrupting it. Python is interpreting certain byte sequences as EOL characters and writing them out as the appropriate EOL for that operating system.  You need to tell Python to open the destination file in binary mode.

Change `d = open(dest,'w')` to `d = open(dest,'wb')` and everything will just work.

Answer (score 6):

For 2.x?

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve(url)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try opening the output file in binary mode:

```
d = open(dest,'wb')
```

(This only matters ion Windows or in Python 3.x.  You are obviously using Python 2.x, but you might be on Windows).